# How do I know that another program is trying to connect to camera being used in my program?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, camera

I made a program that uses a camera with Python.
When my program is using a camera, I would like to add a function that my program detects that another program is trying to connect the camera and cancels the camera connection so that another program can use the camera.

I would like to know if I can see that other programs are trying to use the camera when I am using it, and if so, what is the method?

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture (cv2.CAP_DSHOW + cameraNo)
```

The camera connection uses "cv2.videoCapture()"